# Per-site metas: Inform of impossible badges; And change incorrect "can earn rep" statement

Tags: feature-request, badges, per-site-meta

### Per-site meta badges

Some badges on meta sites are *impossible* to earn on the meta site.

This could cause confusion as the badge is being viewed within the per-meta site's own "badge" area, and so gives the impression it's for that site (meta).

While some badges are arguably obvious, like "*First bounty you manually awarded*", they are likely not so obvious to new-comers.

There are other questions (on MSE) asking for the *impossible badges* to be *removed*, however it's been said these are to remain in place as they "promote" the badges for the sites in general, where they can be earned.
Which is logical/understandable.

**Propose**

Leave the badges in place, but with an asterisk on each badge that cannot be earned on meta, and at the top of the badge tab page:

- * Badges which cannot be earned on meta

Thus removing the *"plastic" dangling carrot* and not confusing new users.

### Top paragraph is untrue

The top paragraph on the badges tab states you can earn rep, which is untrue as you are viewing a per-site meta tab.
(It be all lies I tell thee).

**Propose**

Change the current text on the top of the badges tab to incorporate the fact no rep is earned on meta.
This will remove the current potential for confusion and potential for disgruntled users wondering why their 20 votes got them nadda.

FROM

> Besides gaining reputation with your questions and answers, you
>   receive badges for being especially helpful. Badges appear on your
>   profile page, flair, and your posts.

TO (example only)

> While no rep can be earned on meta, you can still get badges based on
>   what rep *you would have earned* (where possible and without an *).
>   You receive badges for being especially helpful, and badges appear on
>   your profile page, flair, and your posts.

---

At the very least these two issues are misleading, and I think we should be very clear where possible, given there is a lot *happening/to learn* around Stack, especially for new-comers.

Comment: @animuson Why the badge change? I'm not contesting, just asking for future ref/knowledge. I did that as "badges" relates to all sites, and this Q is specifically about "per-site-meta-badges".

Comment: You're asking about [meta-tag:badges] on a [meta-tag:per-site-meta]. We really don't need to go combining them together. If there were a *type of badge* called a "per site meta badge" then that would make more sense as a tag.

Comment: @animuson Ah, yeah that's logical - cheers.